# Adding 2d density contour to connecting lines in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a graph that looks something like this:

[image]

However, I would like to incorporate density based on the connected lines (and not individual plot points, as the graph above using geom_density_2d does). The data, in reality, looks something like this:

[image]

Where I am showing gene expression over a 4-point time series (y = gene expression value, x = time) In both examples, the centre line was created using LOESS curve fitting.

How can I create a density or contour plot based on the actual individual connecting lines that span from time=1 to time=4?

This is what have done so far:

```
# make a dataset 

test <- data.frame(gene=rep(c((1:500)), each=4), 
               time=rep(c(1:4), 125), 
               value=rep(c(1,2,3,1), 125))


# add random noise to dataset

test$value <- jitter(test$value, factor=1,amount=2)


# first graph created as follows: 

ggplot(data=test, aes(x=time, y=value)) + 
geom_density_2d(colour="grey") + 
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,5), 
                 breaks = seq(1,4), 
                 minor_breaks = seq(1)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-3,8)) +
guides(fill=FALSE) +
theme_classic() 


# second plot created as follows

ggplot(test, aes(time, value)) +
geom_line(aes(group = gene), 
        size = 0.5, 
        alpha = 0.3, 
        color = "snow3") +
geom_point() +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-3, 8)) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,4), minor_breaks = seq(1)) +
theme_classic()
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I think an approach that could work would be to use `tweenr` to add intermediate data points that are interpolations of time and value for each gene. Then contour map on that. I haven't gotten it to work yet but maybe someone else with better `tweenr` skills can.